# Include information within a bar graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

df <- population

df |> 
  filter(year == 2010) |>
  arrange(desc(population)) |>
  group_by(country)

df <- df |>
  filter(year == 2010) |>
  mutate(pct = proportions(population) * 100) |>
  filter(country %in% c("China", 
                        "India", 
                        "United States of America", 
                        "Indonesia",
                        "Brazil"))

df |>
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(country, desc(population)), y = pct, fill = fct_reorder(country, desc(population)))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = "Top five countries of the world by population in 2010", 
       x = element_blank(),
       y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Let's assume that in 2010, 80% of the United States population lived in urban areas.

How could I include this information in the graph?

I thought about filling 80% of the green bar (US) with another color in which I would add the following text: Urban Areas (80%).

Comment: You could subset your data into two columns and break out the rural and urban percentages for each country and then do a stacked bar chart

Comment: In my actual data set, I need to include similar information in just one bar out of five bars. Here, I used "population" data as an example.

Comment: you can add text annotations or drop a line across the whole chart, both are easy to do in ggplot. Or you could create two columns and have 100% 0% in all but the one where you need stacking